# SAS: Keep ONLY the highest-valued groups, for Box Plots

Tags: sas

Presently I have so many "groups" when doing Box Plots that the result is SEVEN panels of box plots.

I'd like to have ONE panel, with about 20 box plots (or "groups").

So, that would require cutting out a bunch of groups.

Is there a way to automatically do this?

What I have in mind is:  In a data step, only keep the TOP 20 groups, using Q3 value for each group as the criterion for keeping or removing.

Any coding assistance greatly appreciated.

Nicholas Kormanik

Comment: Please show some sample data and the code you are using.  It's not clear what you mean by "groups" or "Q3" values.  The easiest thing might be to use a `where` clause on multiple invocations of whatever procedure you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing much information but you could sort the data by that value and then save the top 20 like this:

```
proc sort data=myGroups;
by q3;
run;


data myGroupsTop.
set myGroups(obs=20);
run;
```